# phantomjs command not working on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, phantomjs

phantomjs command works perfectly fine on mac local.

However, unable to execute phantomjs command from Jenkins.Build console looks like
+ phantomjs hello.js
/var/folders/vf/hcw165tj0sg3s3p6czn4fz8c00007c/T/hudson6003717517243923017.sh: line 2: phantomjs: command not found

Can you please help on how to configure phantonjs on Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve issue by resolving PATH in JENKINS. PATH in Jenkins now points to executable for PhantomJS. 
I followed [Web page Capture and save to image using phantomjs lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525436/web-page-capture-and-save-to-image-using-phantomjs-lib) and able to save screenshot on my local. 
However when executing PhantomJS command with Jenkins, following error is generated:
"_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL." and screen shot is not saved on Jenkins.

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: If you are asking a new question here, please post as a new question.