# PhantomJS not working with Jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, osx-mountain-lion, phantomjs, screen-capture

I followed [Web page Capture and save to image using phantomjs lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525436/web-page-capture-and-save-to-image-using-phantomjs-lib) and able to save screenshot on my local.

However when executing PhantomJS command with Jenkins, following error is generated: "_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL." and screen shot is not saved on Jenkins.

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Able to resolve the issue by login as Jenkins user

Answer (score 2):

I've found two possible solutions to this problem:

1. As user2325313 commented, if you login as the Jenkins' user you should be able to avoid this issue.
2. Run Jenkins as a standalone application instead of a daemon. To do so, locate your Jenkins `.war` file and execute it from the terminal using the following command :

   `java -jar /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war`